# Custom product multiselect attribute not saving in admin

Tags: multiselect-attribute, source-model

I have created custom product multiselect attribute successfully.

But when i edit the product in admin and selecting some options(countries) of my multiselect attribute and if i click save its saved successfully.

but when i open same product again its not showing before selected options.that means its not saving my custom product attribute to product model.

can you Please help anyone.I'm very tired.and i tried lot of hours.then i'm placing here.

**etc/config.xml file**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Exinent_Shiplimit>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Exinent_Shiplimit>
    </modules>

    <global>
    <models>
       <checkout>
         <rewrite>
           <type_onepage>Exinent_Shiplimit_Model_Checkout_Type_Onepage</type_onepage>
         </rewrite>
        </checkout>
      </models>
    <resources>
            <exinent_shiplimit_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Exinent_Shiplimit</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </exinent_shiplimit_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    </config>
```

**app\code\local\Exinent\Shiplimit\sql\exinent_shiplimit_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php 
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'custom_countries', 
    array(
        'group'             => 'General',
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'backend'           => '',
        'user_defined' => '1',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'label'             => 'Shipping Restricted Countries',
        'input'             => 'multiselect',
        'source'            => 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Countryofmanufacture',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE

    )
);

$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_countries', 'backend_model', '');
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're setting the `backend_model` to `''` it should be `'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array'`

And you'll want to define the type as `text` not `varchar`, since varchar will have lower limit than what is required of the source model.

Take a look around the `eav_attribute` table for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it is just 'backend' instead of 'backend_model'

Comment: If you are using `addAttribute` in setup scripts, it's "backend". In all other cases (`updateAttribute` or directly in the database), it's "backend_model".

Comment: perfect answer with nice explanation!!! +1 :)

Comment: How to set value programatically?

Comment: @jafarpinjar which value are you trying to set specifically?

Comment: I have json data with multi values, need to set it for the attribute created before.